# How can I change display resolution on an GMA 900?

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics

How can i change display resolution with GMA 900 and ubuntu 11.10?

I wonder how can I set up a graphic driver on ubuntu system. I just installed ubuntu 11.10 on my desktop (hewlet packard dc7100 usdt)

I checked system configuration it seems ubuntu doesn't recognize my graphic chip set. I can change resolution only 800x600 and 1024x768. I want to change it 1280X800.

Comment: Has it worked before, or is this your first time using Ubuntu on this machine?

Comment: bntser, it is my first time to use ubuntu on my desktop. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The GMA900 should support the 1280x780 resolution according to the [product spec page from HP](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/11948_div/11948_div.HTML#Technical%20Specifications%20-%20Graphics).

Try installing a graphics driver using the 'Additional Drivers', search for it in the dash and run it.

It will let you know what driver may be available.

You may also have to follow the advice on this related question [Getting drivers to work for intel gma 950](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84385/getting-drivers-to-work-for-intel-gma-950)