# Getting drivers to work for intel gma 950

Tags: 11.10, drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel

I recently switched over my netbook to Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm having issues with detecting the graphics chipset.

The closest I've come to finding a solution that does not require messing with git (something I'm not ready to do) is [this](http://www.jacoblog.net/2011/10/29/ubuntu-11-10-intel-driver-problem/). However this seems to be for the 915(M?) chipset and I haven't been able to figure out the grub line-change (i.e. "i915.modeset=1") that works for my chipset. Does anyone know which line I should use/or another way to get ubuntu to recognize my chipset?

Answer (score 3):

"i915" is the actual driver for most, if not all, currently supported intel GPUs. Just add `i915.modeset=1` as is, and see what happens. You also have to run `sudo update-grub` after making the changes - something the author forgot to mention.